# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Transitions Don't Work on Mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I have two different sites where TWBS carousel transitions don't work in mobile.  They work fine in the browser.  On one site the CSS is compiled from LESS and on the other from SASS.  If I override my compiled CSS with the CDN CSS, so basically have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">` in the HEAD after my CSS, the transitions work.  The problem seemed to start when upgrading to the latest version of TWBS (3.3.1) as they worked with earlier versions.  Has anyone else run into this and found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably ran into https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14937
The proper way to fix this is to add [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) to your build process so that the necessary vendor prefixes are added to the generated CSS.